# Problems importing @turf module in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, turfjs

I have been using turf for a while in nodejs, no problem.
I recently added a new turf module in a server:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@turf/union": "^6.3.0",
    ...
  }
```

When I try to import that module:

```
const union = require('@turf/union').default;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: No valid exports main found for '/opt/app/node_modules/@turf/union'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:9)
    ...
```

Now I have been using that import syntax without a problem on some other module, for instance `@turf/destination`. So I went to the server using that syntax.
I updated `@turf/destination` from "^6.0.1" to the latest (6.3....), and I get the same import error. Revert back to 6.0.1 and all is fine.

What should I try? Thanks!

---

I just installed the following:

```
    "@turf/helpers": "6.1.4"
    "@turf/invariant": "6.1.2"
    "@turf/union": "6.0.1"
```

(replicating the same rev level as my server which uses `@turf/destination`) and all is fine. So the latest turf modules expect a different import strategy, I just cannot find what....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using node `13.5.0`?

I read the type definition of the library, there is no change to their import behaviour and `.default` should be supported.

I can reproduce your problem with node 13. Can you try to upgrade to node `14+`?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I am using the Docker node:13.6-alpine image as a base. I'll try to bump up the release number and see what gives, thanks!

Comment: I tried 13.6, also has the same problem, it should be the cause. cheers!